# Splitting two concatenated terms in python

Tags: python

In general I have a string say

```
temp = "ProgramFields"
```

Now I want to split strings like these into two terms(I can identify tow strings based on uppercase character)

```
term1  = "Program"
term2  = "Field"
```

How to achieve this in python?
I tried regular expression and splitting terms but nothing gave me the result that I expected
Python code -

```
re.split("[A-Z][a-z]*","ProgramField")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include groups:

```
re.split('([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'ProgramField)
```